# comparing rows in sql on two different columns

Tags: sql

```
id address retailer
1   A        11
2   A         11
3   A         11
4   A         12
5   A         13
6   B         12
7   B         12
8   B         13
```

My output should be

```
id address retailer
1   A        11
4   A         12
5   A         13
6   B         12
8   B         13
```

i.e my query should return id's which have **same address but not same retailer.**

How toget this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're joining on columns with no duplicates, which is by far the most common case:

- An `inner join` of `A` and `B` gives the result of `A intersect B`, i.e. the inner part of a venn diagram intersection.
- An `outer join` of `A` and `B` gives the results of `A union B`, i.e. the outer parts of a venn diagram union.

---

### Examples:

Suppose you have two Tables, with a single column each, and data as follows:

```
A    B
-    -
1    3
2    4
3    5
4    6
```

Note that (1,2) are unique to `A`, (3,4) are common, and (5,6) are unique to `B`.

**`Inner join`**:

An `inner join` using either of the equivalent queries gives the intersection of the two tables, i.e. the two rows they have in common.

```
select * 
from a 
INNER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;

select a.*,b.*  
from a,b 
where a.a = b.b;

a | b
--+--
3 | 3
4 | 4
```

**`Left outer join`**:

A `left outer join` will give all rows in A, plus any common rows in B.

```
select * 
from a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;
select a.*,b.*  
from a,b 
where a.a = b.b(+);

a |  b  
--+-----
1 | null
2 | null
3 |    3
4 |    4
```

**`Full outer join`**:

A `full outer join` will give you the union of `A` and `B`, i.e. All the rows in A and all the rows in B. If something in A doesn't have a corresponding datum in B, then the B portion is null, and vice versa.

```
select * 
from a 
FULL OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;

 a   |  b  
-----+-----
   1 | null
   2 | null
   3 |    3
   4 |    4
null |    6
null |    5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `group by` clause as below:

```
select min(id), address, retailer
from tab
group by address, retailer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(id) as id,address, retailer 
from table1 
group by address, retailer
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you need is:

```
SELECT min(id), address, retailer
FROM table1 AS t1
group by address, retailer
order by address
```

Here's the [source](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34c4e/5/0)

Comment: my output should contain rows which have same address but not the same retailer

Comment: Hope you've checked the link I have given you in my answer. It gives you the exact output as you've mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use This: It's working:

```
 SELECT * FROM `sampletable` GROUP BY address, retailer
```